# Does one need the Hahn-Banach theorem to prove the mean value inequality for maps into a normed space?

Tags: real-analysis, vector-spaces, normed-spaces

Consider the following mean value theorem:

*If $f$ is a continuous mapping of $\,[a,b]$ into a normed linear space $X$, **whose norm doesn't derive from an inner product**, and $f$ is differentiable on $]a,b[$, there exists $c \in \,]a,b[$ such that $$\left\| \frac {f(b)-f(a)}{b-a} \right\| \le \|f'(c)\|$$*

Now I ask if one can prove it **by contradiction** starting from the auxiliary function $$\varphi(t)=\left\| \frac {f(b)-f(a)}{b-a} \right\|(t-a)-\|f(t)-f(a)\| \qquad (\,t \in [a,b]\,)$$ My contribution is rather poor.

I note that $\varphi$ is continuous on $[a,b]\,$ and $\,\varphi(a)=\varphi(b)=0$.

Supposed $$\left\| \frac {f(b)-f(a)}{b-a} \right\| > \|f'(c)\| \qquad \forall \,c \in \,]a,b[$$ I think to prove that $\varphi$ is **strictly** monotonic on $[a,b]$, so that $\varphi(a) \neq \varphi(b)$, a contradiction.

Unfortunately I stop when I begin to differentiate $\|f(t)-f(a)\|$ to find $\varphi'$.

Does someone know more ? Thanks in advance.

**meaning of the title**:

Typically the proof uses an inner product if it is available.
If it doesn't exist, one appeals to the Hahn-Banach theorem to find a functional as a substitute of the inner product (see theorem 1.2.1, p. 3 in [this book](http://books.google.it/books?id=gqrsUK5Y6EwC&printsec=frontcover&dq=differential+equations+in+abstract+spaces&hl=it&sa=X&ei=-I75U-GTNYe1PJGWgbAD&ved=0CCIQ6AEwAA#v=onepage&q=differential%20equations%20in%20abstract%20spaces&f=false)).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A proof without using a norming linear functional for $f(b)-f(a)$ can be found in the 2nd edition of Rudin's *Principles of Mathematical Analysis*. It's stated for Euclidean space, but it works the same for all normed spaces. (Trivia: when the 2nd  edition was translated into Russian, the translator added a footnote with the linear-functional proof; subsequently, Rudin replaced  the proof in the 3rd edition).

The idea is to use the triangle inequality to show that $f$ must have certain rate of change on smaller and smaller subintervals; then take intersection over a chain of subintervals. Care must be taken to ensure the intersection is an *interior* point of $[a,b]$.

Following Rudin's notation, let $L=(b-a)/3$ and $M=\|f(b)-f(a)\|$. The function $g(x)=\|f(x+L)-f(x)\|$ satisfies $g(a)+g(a+L)+g(a+2L)\ge M$ by the triangle inequality. It follows  that $g(x)\ge M/3$ for some $x_1\in (a,a+2L)$, for otherwise we would have
$$g(a)\le \frac{M}{3}, \quad  g(a+L)<\frac{M}{3}, \quad  g(a+2L) \le \frac{M}{3}$$
Replace out original interval $I_0=[a,b]$ with $I_1=[x_1,x_1+L]$ and repeat. (Note that $I_1\subset (a,b)$.)

Let $x_*=\bigcap_n I_n$. The endpoints of $I_n$ form two sequences $s_n,t_n$ converging to $x_*$ from opposite directions. Since $$\frac{\|f(t_n)-f(s_n)\|}{|t_n-s_n|}\ge \frac{\|f(b)-f(a)\|}{|b-a|}$$   it follows that $$\|f'(x_*)\|\ge \frac{\|f(b)-f(a)\|}{|b-a|}$$

---

#### Note

The more intuitive approach of repeated bisection does not guarantee we get an interior point. However, after $I_1$ was obtained above, subsequent steps could be bisection.

Comment: Probably the proof contained in Rudin's book (1964) originates in a paper by Aziz and Diaz _On A Mean Value Theorem of the Differential Calculus of Vector-Valued Functions, etc._ (1961). Really I would like to know something about the differentiability (ordinary or one-sided) of the norm of a vector function of one real variable.

Comment: @TonyPiccolo One-sided derivatives of $\|f\|$ exist, two-sided generally don't (but they exist in smooth spaces). Since $f$ is differentiable (admits linear approximation), this is the question of whether $t\mapsto \|x+tv\|$ is differentiable. One-sided derivatives exist since the function is convex. Two-sided may fail to exist, e.g., in $l^1$, $l^\infty$.

Comment: Your comment confirms my suspicion: the idea works (probably). One proves that $\varphi_+'$ exists and is positive so $\varphi$ is strictly monotonic. The only thing I don't know is a relation between $(\|f(t)-f(a)\|)_+'$ and $\|(f(t)-f(a))_+'\|=\|f'(t)\|$.

Comment: @TonyPiccolo Since $ |\|f(t)\|-\|f(a)\||\le \|f(t)-f(a)\|$, there is an inequality when both derivatives exist.

Comment: Then it works ! The last thing I ask you is a reference relative to your comments. Thank you very much.

Comment: @TonyPiccolo *Nonlinear Functional Analysis* by Deimling, page 49 and section 13.1