# Does $ F$ have expansion in the form $F(y) = F(x) + \nabla F(\bar{x}) (y -x) + o(y-x)$?

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, functional-analysis

Let $F: X \to Y$ be continuously differentiable around $\bar{x} \in X$. where $X$ and $Y$ are Banach normed spaces. Then prove that F can be represented as follow

$$  F(y) = F(x) + \nabla F(\bar{x}) (y -x) + o(y-x)$$

where  $\lim_{(x,y) \to (\bar{x} , \bar{x} )}  \frac{o(y-x)}{\|y-x \|}  = 0$

In another word I want to prove that

$$ \lim_{(x,y) \to (\bar{x} , \bar{x} )} \frac{F(y) - F(x) + \nabla F(\bar{x}) (y -x) } {\|y-x\|} =0               $$

Comment: This is more or less the definition of [(Frechet) differentiability](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fréchet_derivative), right--or are you using another definition?

Comment: @eepperly16  No It's not. I will edit my question to make it more clear for you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, this is true. The property you are asking for is known as 'strict differentiability'.

It can be proven as follows.
We define
$$g(x) := f(x) - f'(\bar x)(x - \bar x).$$
From the mean value theorem ([Necessity of the Hahn Banach Theorem for the Gateaux Mean Value Theorem](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3075286/necessity-of-the-hahn-banach-theorem-for-the-gateaux-mean-value-theorem)) it follows
\begin{align*}
\frac{\| f(x) - f(y) - f'(\bar x)(x-y)\|}{\|x-y\|}&=
\frac{\| g(x) - g(y) \|}{\|x-y\|}\\ &\le \sup_{t \in [0,1]} \| g'(x + t \, (y-x))\|
= \sup_{t \in [0,1]} \| f'(x + t \, (y-x)) - f'(\bar x)\| \to 0
\end{align*}
as $x,y \to \bar x$.